# How can I specify a TypeScript type when passing an object into a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function:

```
export default function AppNavbar({ isEditor }) {
```

I want to specify that `isEditor` is `boolean`.

I tried:

```
export default function AppNavbar({ isEditor: boolean }) {
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: type t = {filterList: boolean}; export default function AppNavbar({obj: t}) {}; Something like this is usually used.

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, however the syntax you tried is already used in JavaScript for [aliasing destructured variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names).

You can annotate destructured function parameters like this:

```js
type ItemType = {
  isEditor: boolean;
};

// The type needs to be specified after the parameter:
function doSomething({isEditor}: ItemType) {
  const alias: boolean = isEditor;
}

// Inline type annotation works too:
function doSomethingElse({isEditor}: {isEditor: boolean}) {
  const alias: boolean = isEditor;
}

// You can't type the destructured fields because that syntax is already used
// for aliasing the destructured parameters. Here, 'isEditor' is aliased to 
// 'someOtherVariableName'.
function doSomethingWithAliasedArg({isEditor: someOtherVariableName}: ItemType) {
  // Notice 'someOtherVariableName' is used instead of 'isEditor'
  const alias: boolean = someOtherVariableName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the type after the parameter, e.g.

```
export default function AppNavbar({ isEditor }: {isEditor: boolean}) {...
```